# Unable to upload html file from Jenkins to Slack channel

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, slack, slack-api, newman

I am sending build start, success and failure notification to slack channel which is working fine only upload file is not working. I am using same token for sending notifications to slack channel which works fine. Not sure how to pass the token in upload file slack api.

I have used below in my pipeline script.

```
        sh 'curl --request POST \
        --url https://slack.com/api/files.upload \
        --form token=$SLACK_CREDENTIAL_ID \
        --form channels=channel_name \
        --form file=@newman/Sanity.html'
```

Getting error: {"ok":false,"error":"not_authed"}

How to pass token here? as its not reading the token

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the bot key didn't have rights to upload the file. Once I used the bot key which has upload rights it worked.